# Can we set "Content Explorer" page as default landing page in Tridion?

Tags: cme

I'm wondering is there a setting available in CM to configure default landing page of CM as "Content Explorer" after login?

At the moment, I have explored setting "Start Location" option as per following document http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-04BAA436-A880-4CD0-9FD2-AA3EE75E8ACE, but this sets start location only within Content Explorer. I can directly open the “Content Explorer” page, if I hit/login with the following url: `http://<CMserver>/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=cme`, however I'm looking for the configuration change.

Appreciate your inputs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, if you just browse to the root of the application (e.g. `http://<CMserver>/`) then this will load the 'Home' screen and update the URL to the following: `http://<CMserver>/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=home`

It appears that this default behaviour is 'under the hood' and cannot be updated without editing the core Tridion files - Thus invalidating your support agreement with SDL.

[image: Screenshot of JavaScript code defining what the home location is]

Other options that you may want to consider, could include:

1. Distribute the full Content Explorer URL (`http://<CMserver>/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=cme`) to editors, so that they go directly to this option where possible. They can also bookmark this URL in their browsers.
2. Use a URL shortening tool (such as [bitly](https://bitly.com) or [Goo.gl](https://goo.gl/)) to create a shortened URL that redirects to the Content Explorer (`http://<CMserver>/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=cme`)
3. Intercept requests to the root URL (`http://<CMserver>/`) at the load balancer (if you're using one) and rewrite these to go to the Content Explorer URL
4. Writing a [GUI extension](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-44562CE1-5D81-4E64-B65B-C8BFA0BAA53D) to recognise requests to the root/home URL and rewrite them to go to the Content Explorer URL (`http://<CMserver>/SDL/#app=wcm&entry=cme`) - I have not tried this to see whether it's actually possible!
5. Encourage each of your users to make the root of the Content Explorer a favourite. Although this still requires an extra click, it makes it easier for your editors to find the main CME interface from the 'Home' screen.

[image: Screenshot of Home favourites]

Answer (score 4):

[Earlier versions had a view settings on the old dashboard](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%202011%20SP1%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-7555B5A9-45C1-4E4D-9E57-FF012ED02142), which has since been replaced by the [Slide-out Navigation Home Screen](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B6A8BC26-E888-47D9-B7FD-6C77086ECAD3) and [user preferences](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-A9A92E01-31E2-46C6-AF7A-357040BAFE83).

These settings were influenced by user AppData and the CME.config (see [this StackExchange question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11958962/395495)). I'm not sure they still apply for 2013 SP1 (possibly not), but note changing them is not supported. This means if making a change to CME.config breaks the system, Support can't help you fix it.

In practice, I know organizations may take calculated chances and modify the non-supported parts of configuration files (always make a backup and test on DEV).

*Product wise we are looking to improve the editor's experience--I'll mention this to UX, but it maybe be awhile before something like this is in the product.*

For now, I'd have editors bookmark that starting URL, maybe make a links to it, or have them select it when browsers suggest urls.